# Copiar archivos y directorios de una carpeta local a una carpeta remota en linux

Tags: linux, terminal

Tengo el siguiente comando:

```
scp -rp "C:\Users\User\Desktop\CarpetaOrigen\*"/ root@111.111.111.111:/root/CarpetaDestino
```

CarpetaOrigen

- Carpeta1

  - ArchivoInterno1.txt
  - ArchivoInterno2.txt
- Carpeta2

  - ArchivoInterno3.txt
  - ArchivoInterno4.txt
- Archivo1.txt
- Archivo2.txt

Lo que quiero es copiar todo el contenido de la CarpetaOrigen a la Carpeta destino (via ssh), sin embargo solo me copia las carpetas y sus archivos internos (Carpeta1 y Carpeta2 ambas con sus respectivos txt), pero los archivos sueltos (Archivo1.txt y Archivo2.txt) que estan fuera de las carpetas no me los copia, que le falta a mi comando?

Gracias.

Comment: Puedes probar sin la `/` al final de la ruta de origen?

Comment: @FedericoMeza, muchas gracias esa fue la solucion al problema!!! llevaba horas buscando la solucion, gracias nuevamente,